# How to put functional value in Google chart?

Tags: charts

I want to use functional value in Google visualization chart. But this is not working, why? I am using the following code:

```
 google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
          ['2004',  200,    <script language="Javascript">display('2')</script>],
          ['2005',  1170,      460],
          ['2006',  660,       1120],
          ['2004',  200,      400],
          ['2005',  1170,      460],
          ['2006',  660,       1120],


          ['2007',  1030,      540]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance',
          hAxis: {title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

Comment: Define `functional value`

Comment: how to define  functional value?

Comment: `i want to use functional value in google visualization chart` - what do you mean with `using functional value`?

Comment: that means i want to call the value of a function inside the chart instead of using direct value.for example i am calling display('2') here but this not showing any value rater it's making error!!